# Change display of UITableview

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, ios5, ios6

when I launch my app on iOS6 the display of the UITableview is the one i want, which is the same as the mail application tableview, but when I launch it in on the iOS5 simulator the tableview corresponds to the settings application one. How do I get the mail app tableview for both iOS versions?

Answer (score 1):

you set the table views property "style" there are 2: UITableViewStylePlain,
   UITableViewStyleGrouped. plain is the regular one with the white row, grouped is the ones you see in the settings application.

```
tableView.style = UITableViewStylePlain;
```

You could also set this in IB/StoryBoard by clicking on the table view looking to the right clicking on the Attribute Inspector and looking for the option Style.

[image]